# underscore each method not running through the complete backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js, each

I have a table that I am populating when new items are added to a collection and I am populated a deleted items collection when Items are deleted from that collection.

Then I have a single save button, that triggers the save/delete events on the collections.

Saves are working just fine but only half of my deletes are working and I am confused.

```
class MyApp.Collections.DeletedTasks extends Backbone.Collection
  model: MyApp.Models.Task

  destroy: () ->
    console.log('destroy the collection size: ' + @.models.length)
    _.each(@.models, @sendDelete)

  sendDelete: (model) ->
    console.log('deleting model with id: ' + model.get('id'))
    model.destroy()
```

Console output

```
Done with Adding/Updating Collections
destroy the collection size: 6
deleting model with id: KSc18d06fefddbebd2ade74bcab4c670c907
deleting model with id: KS07cb95935b1caf3817758739224a3e1a2f
deleting model with id: KS6f473b3e15740fe7c6c0909e14986700a9
```

What happened? 
Why did it only do 3?
How do I debug this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

copy the collection to an array first.  You're removing from a collection that is being enumerated.  I'm not a coffee script guru but something like:

`_.each(@.models.toArray(), @sendDelete)`

Comment: _.each(@.toArray(), @sendDelete)

Comment: Cool--and thx for the coffeescript correction :) (need to learn that)

Answer (score 4):

Tim already gave a fine answer, but there's a better way:

Underscore's iteration methods are already a part of Backbone collections, which means that instead of

```
_.each(@.models, @sendDelete)
```

you can simply write

```
@each(@sendDelete)
```

That also takes care of converting `@models` to an array for you, preventing `destroy()` from messing up the iteration.

You should never have to use `@models` directly; it should be thought of as an internal property, like `@attributes` on models.